# $\int_x^{2x} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^4+t^2+1}} $ variation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

How can I study  the variation   of function $f$  and represent them graphically $$ f(x)=\int_x^{2x} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^4+t^2+1}}$$

Comment: By variation, do you mean derivative? What have you tried?

Comment: @folouer of kaklas  Yes, signe of derivative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

Let $$f(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^4+t^2+1}}$$

$f $ is continuous at $ \Bbb R.$

For any real $ x$, put
$$F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$$

then

$$F'(x)=f(x)$$
and
$$g(x)=F(2x)-F(x)$$

So,
$$g'(x)=2f(2x)-f(x)$$

Comment: A while ago I found a solution I used this method ,thanks

Comment: I request you to read the following guidelines that I attach [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1)

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I will do so. Thank you very much. I appreciate. thanx again.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Welcome!